# I want to use the IEventHandler of iText 7 to be able to add the same Paragraph to every header when creating a new page

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, itext7

This is my code

```
package com.genpdfwithitext.genpdfwithitext
import com.itextpdf.kernel.events.Event
import com.itextpdf.kernel.events.IEventHandler
import com.itextpdf.kernel.events.PdfDocumentEvent
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph

class HandlePdfEvent : IEventHandler {
    override fun handleEvent(event: Event?) {
        println("Handle Event Method actived")
        val docEvent = event as PdfDocumentEvent
        var pdfDoc = docEvent.document
        var page = docEvent.page
        var doc = Document(pdfDoc)
        doc.add(Paragraph("Header!!!"))
    }
}
```

```
package com.genpdfwithitext.genpdfwithitext

import com.itextpdf.kernel.events.PdfDocumentEvent
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/generatePdf")
class pdfController {

    val SRC = "C:\\\\genpdfwithitext\\\\src\\\\main\\\\resources\\\\testPdf.pdf"
    val dest = "C:\\\\genpdfwithitext\\\\src\\\\main\\\\resources\\\\destPdf.pdf"

    @GetMapping("/testGenPdf")
    fun testGenPdf() : String{
        try {
            var reader = PdfReader(SRC)
            var write = PdfWriter(dest)
            //var pdfDoc = PdfDocument(reader,write)
            var pdfDoc = PdfDocument(write)
            val eventHandler = HandlePdfEvent()
            pdfDoc.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.START_PAGE , eventHandler  )
            var document = Document(pdfDoc)
            var p = Paragraph("Test")
//            p.setFixedPosition(212f,623f,30f)
            for(i in 1..50){
                document.add(p)
            }
            document.close()
            return "Connected Completed"
        }catch (e : Exception){
            e.printStackTrace()
            throw e
        }
    }
}
```

this is my result
Page 1
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XADCT.png)
Page 2
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZV3R.png)

I want to use the IEventHandler of iText 7 to be able to add the same Paragraph to every header when creating a new page.

I used to work with iText 5, but when I tried it with iText 7, it didn't work. Please help.

Comment: *"I used to work with iText 5"* - adding text to the `Document` in iText 5 page events had been recommended against by iText development, it only works to a certain degree and not by design.